# Conversion of Plsql function to support snowflake

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some help here to convert the below oracle function to Snowflake sql. The requirement here is the below code converts the local currency amount to USD for with the specific rate at the particular date.
Condition here is we dont have dates below 2017, so whatever the contracts created should pick the minimum value from that particular table for that respective currency, and if there are any future contracts which is more than sysdate, then it shoudl pick latest (max rate) dates rate for that currency.
Please help me here.

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION get_exchange_rate(
      p_rate_amount     IN NUMBER,
      p_exchange_source IN VARCHAR2,
      p_exchange_target IN VARCHAR2,
      p_date            IN DATE)
    RETURN NUMBER
  is
  l_rate number := null;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT exchange_rate
      INTO l_rate
      FROM exchange_rate_table
      WHERE exchange_period='Daily'
      AND exchange_target  =p_exchange_target
      AND exchange_source  =p_exchange_source
      AND begin_effect_date=p_date;
      RETURN l_rate*p_rate_amount;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      SELECT exchange_rate
      INTO l_rate
      FROM exchange_rate_table
      WHERE exchange_period='Daily'
      AND exchange_target  =p_exchange_target
      AND exchange_source  =p_exchange_source
      AND begin_effect_date=
        (SELECT MIN(begin_effect_date)
        FROM exchange_rate_table
        where 1 = 1
        and exchange_source = p_exchange_source
        AND exchange_target  =p_exchange_target
        );
      RETURN l_rate*p_rate_amount;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      return null;
    END;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END get_exchange_rate;
```

Sample Data:

[image]

Desired result :
[image]

Explanation :

In exchange table we have all the conversion rates from all source currencies to target currencies for all the exchange periods like Daily, Monthly,Annual.
Here in my scenario, All the source currencies should convert to target currencies as USD for that respective dates(daily rates) . like matching dates, with matching source currency codes.

When we dont have currency rates for particular local currency to USD :

Here in this case, exchange dim table has started from 01-10-2021, where contracted started on 01-09-2021, then it should pick minimum date from exchange table, (lets say in case of EUR currency.) And at the same time, we may have contracts which starts from future dates also, in that case we should pick maximum date currency rate. (eg CAD currency)

My code in snowflake:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Hi ,Can someone help me handling this above scenario in snowflake .

Comment: Hi - this isn’t a free code writing service, unfortunately. You need to at least attempt to write your SP in Snowflake and then you can ask a question about a specific issue you are facing

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your feedback. I am updating my snowflake code on answers , where in this code is working fine individually but not able to fit into the main query due to the error unsupported subquery . Well also I am not aware of my code trials should be needed.